# How should the proverb "能ある鷹は爪を隠す" be understood?

Tags: translation, set-phrases

The [literal translation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%83%BD%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E9%B7%B9%E3%81%AF%E7%88%AA%E3%82%92%E9%9A%A0%E3%81%99) of "能ある鷹は爪を隠す" is “The wise hawk hides its talons.”

But what should I understand the proverb as meaning? Is it just about humbleness, or about not letting your adversaries know what you're capable of?

Comment: http://kotowaza-allguide.com/no/noutakatsumekakusu.html

Comment: Similar to "Keep your friends close, but your enemies closer"?  Not the same, but I'm not aware of a colloquial equivalent in English.

Comment: @kiss-o-matic thanks, but I'm more after understanding the phrase, rather than looking for similar English proverbs.

Comment: Cheers.  I think your interpretation is pretty spot on.

Comment: 創真「[調理場で語りすぎる料理人の腕は、信用ならねえってのが常識だぜ](http://snowwind38.jugem.jp/?cid=14) 」 [Picture](http://img-cdn.jg.jugem.jp/a7e/2307686/20150516_1075983.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes the moral of a proverb could be vague and ambiguous.

The author of [this page](http://daibutsuda.blog26.fc2.com/blog-entry-654.html) believes that it tells people to "behave humbly", while [this one](http://www.geocities.co.jp/Milkyway-Kaigan/2877/essay/nouarutaka.htm) argues that it means "wise people know how to let others' guard down", which is more or less faithful to what original hawks are said to do. There's also a [QA forum answer](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1198878736) gives an insight that "truly talented people don't need to show them off because they know they can exert it anytime they want". And [this writer](http://meigen.shiawasehp.net/prov/107.html) is apparently unsure about the true connotation of this idiom:

> 能力を隠すのは、 *They hide their abilities...*
>   　そのほうがカッコいいから？ *because it's cool?*
>   　まわりの人とうまくやっていくため？ *to get along with others?*
>   　出る杭（は打たれる）にならないため？ *because don't want to be "the nail sticks out"?*
>   　人を油断させるため？ *to let their guards down?*
>   　人に利用されないため？ *not to be taken advantage of?*
>   　能力をひけらかす必要などないから？ *because they don't feel a need to show off?*
>   　人間としての成長を目指すため（謙譲の美徳）？ *for character building (humbleness)?*

After all, perhaps it could be concluded that the spirit of a proverb resides in how they understand it.

P.S. I can't keep hiding the fact that [I've incidentally used this expression recently](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19849769#19849769) :D